# How to correct IBM MQ Error when SSL is enabled

Tags: java, ssl, ibm-mq

We have enabled SSL on

1. MQ version '7.1.0.7'
2. OS->'Linux 2.6.32-642.11.1.el6.x86_64'
3. two months back [aug-2016] and its working fine with SSL enabled and disabled mode

Java Client uses

1. jdk1.7.0_21
2. Worked cipher/suite -> `SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA <> RC4_SHA_US`

When I try to connect to a MQ v7.1.0.7 queue manager the application is throwing below error:

```
 com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2397'.
         at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.<init>(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:228)
         at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11._createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:553)
         at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:593)
         at com.ibm.mq.StoredManagedConnection.<init>(StoredManagedConnection.java:95)
         at com.ibm.mq.MQSimpleConnectionManager.allocateConnection(MQSimpleConnectionManager.java:198)
         at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.obtainBaseMQQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:882)
```

**In the queue manager error log `AMQERR01.LOG` I see this:**

```
AMQ9616: The CipherSpec proposed is not enabled on the server.

 EXPLANATION: The SSL or TLS subsystem at the server end of a channel
 been configured in such a way that it has rejected the CipherSpec
 proposed by an SSL or TLS client. This rejection occurred during the
 secure socket handshake (i.e. it happened before the proposed
 CipherSpec was compared with the CipherSpec in the server channel
 definition).
```

We have a **MQ v6.0.2.12** queue manager where this is working fine.

Could some one provide help what went wrong for system , which was working before?

Resolved by adding below lines in qm.ini file

```
SSL:
    AllowSSLV3=Y
    AllowWeakCipherSpec=Y
```

> ***Updated (2017/01/27) with additional questions:***

Worked below **TLSv1**

1. `TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA       SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA        TLSv1   TRUE`
2. `TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA  SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA   TLSv1   TRUE`

Failed with **TLSv1.2**

1. `TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA256    SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA        TLSv1.2 FALSE`

I tried with these settings:

1. `SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1");`
2. `-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.preferTLS=true`
3. `-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false`

Error is `com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2397'`

In the `AMQERR01.LOG`

```
There is a mismatch between the CipherSpecs on the local and remote ends
of channel 'TEST.CH'. The channel will not run until this mismatch is 
resolved.The CipherSpec required in the local channel definition is 
'TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA256'. The name of the CipherSpec negotiated during
the SSL handshake is 'RC4_SHA_US'. A code is displayed if the name of the
negotiated CipherSpec cannot be determined
```

> **Updated (2017/01/29) with additional questions:**

1. `SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");`
2. `MQEnvironment.sslFipsRequired = true;`
3. `MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite ="SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256";`
4. `ALTER CHANNEL(TEST.CH) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) SSLCIPH(TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256)`
5. `REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(SSL)`
6. Client Execute
   `/apps/java/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/java -Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.preferTLS=true  -Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false -classpath .:/tmp/mqssl/com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:/tmp/mqssl/com.ibm.mq.jar:com.ibm.ws.webservices.thinclient_8.5.0.jar MQProducerSSL`

**Getting error as `MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2400'`**
`MQRC_UNSUPPORTED_CIPHER_SUITE (2400)`

> **Updated (2017/01/30) with additional questions:**

Still same error , but in my client java prg have enabled `System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "all");` to see all activities  while execute client. Its Printing `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256` as `Ignoring unavailable cipher suite` as below

```
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
```

**Before call**

```
MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2400'.  
MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2400'.
```

**Tested with IBM-JDK-71 Same Exception**
SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA<><>ECDHE_ECDSA_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA256
SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA<><>ECDHE_RSA_NULL_SHA256

> **Updated (2017/01/31) with additional questions:**

**com.ibm.mq.jar**

```
Specification-Version: 7.1.0.1  
Specification-Vendor: IBM Corporation  
Implementation-Title: WebSphere MQ classes for Java  
Implementation-Version: 7.1.0.1 - k710-001-120424
```

**com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar**

```
Specification-Version: 7.1.0.1  
Specification-Vendor: IBM Corporation  
Implementation-Title: WebSphere MQ Interface for Java  
Implementation-Version: 7.1.0.1 - k710-001-120424
```

> **Updated (2017/01/31 A) with additional questions:**

Since MQ and Client Running in same machine ,got **Specification-Version: 7.1.0.7** jars
**Testing done with 2 scenarios**  by changing the classpath

1. **Without** `-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false`

`jdk1.7.0_21/bin/java -Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.preferTLS=true -classpath .:/opt/mqm/java/lib/com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:/opt/mqm/java/lib/com.ibm.mq.jar MQProducerSSL`

got exception `MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2400'`

2. **With** `-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false`

`/apps/hostlink/java/jdk1.7.0_21/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/java -Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.preferTLS=true -Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=true -classpath .:/opt/mqm/java/lib/com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:/opt/mqm/java/lib/com.ibm.mq.jar MQProducerSSL`

got exception `MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2393'`

```
com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2393'.  
at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.<init>(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:232)  
at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11._createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:553)  
at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:593)  
at com.ibm.mq.StoredManagedConnection.<init>(StoredManagedConnection.java:96)  
at com.ibm.mq.MQSimpleConnectionManager.allocateConnection(MQSimpleConnectionManager.java:198)  
at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.obtainBaseMQQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:893)  
at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.procure(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:780)  
at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.constructQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:729)  
at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.createQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:177)  
at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.<init>(MQQueueManager.java:674)  
at MQProducerSSL.main(MQProducerSSL.java:89)  
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2393;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'localhost(2017)' rejected. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2393;AMQ9771: SSL handshake failed. [1=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException[Cannot support TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 with currently installed providers],3=localhost/127.0.0.1:2017 (localhost),4=SSLSocket.createSocket,5=default]],3=localhost(2017),5=RemoteTCPConnection.makeSocketSecure]
```

> **Updated (2017/01/31 B) with additional questions:**

```
MQEnvironment.sslFipsRequired = false;  
MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256";  
ALTER CHANNEL(TEST.CH) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) SSLCIPH(TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256)  
/apps/hostlink/java/jdk1.7.0_21/jdk1.7.0_21/bin/java -Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.preferTLS=true -Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false -classpath .:/opt/mqm/java/lib/com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:/opt/mqm/java/lib/com.ibm.mq.jar MQProducerSSL
```

**MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2397'.**

```
MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2397'.
com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2397'.
        at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.<init>(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:232)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11._createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:553)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:593)
        at com.ibm.mq.StoredManagedConnection.<init>(StoredManagedConnection.java:96)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQSimpleConnectionManager.allocateConnection(MQSimpleConnectionManager.java:198)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.obtainBaseMQQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:893)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.procure(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:780)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.constructQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:729)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.createQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:177)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.<init>(MQQueueManager.java:674)
        at MQProducerSSL.main(MQProducerSSL.java:89)
```

**Worked below TLSv1**

----Spec---- `TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA`
---Suite---- `SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA`
TLSv1   TRUE

```
Not working , when given below parameters , throwing **MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2400'** 

-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false  
-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.preferTLS=true
```

doubt on TLSv1 , if TLSv1 working without above parameters , why need to provide -Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.preferTLS=true for TLSv2?

even with IBM-JDK 7.1 also TLSv2 not working, what could be issue?
Need to try with MQ8?

> **Updated (2017/02/01) with additional questions:**

**Complete Exception in console**

```
MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2397'.
com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2397'.
        at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.<init>(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:232)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11._createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:553)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:593)
        at com.ibm.mq.StoredManagedConnection.<init>(StoredManagedConnection.java:96)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQSimpleConnectionManager.allocateConnection(MQSimpleConnectionManager.java:198)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.obtainBaseMQQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:893)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.procure(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:780)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.constructQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:729)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.createQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:177)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.<init>(MQQueueManager.java:674)
        at MQProducerSSL.main(MQProducerSSL.java:89)
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'localhost(2017)' rejected. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9771: SSL handshake failed. [1=javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException[Error signing certificate verify],3=localhost/127.0.0.1:2017 (localhost),4=SSLSocket.startHandshake,5=default]],3=localhost(2017),5=RemoteTCPConnection.protocolConnect]
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:2098)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1347)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQSESSION.MQCONNX_j(MQSESSION.java:924)
        at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.<init>(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:221)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2397;AMQ9771: SSL handshake failed. [1=javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException[Error signing certificate verify],3=localhost/127.0.0.1:2017 (localhost),4=SSLSocket.startHandshake,5=default]
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.protocolConnect(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1310)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.connect(RemoteConnection.java:714)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSessionFromNewConnection(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:356)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSession(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:265)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionPool.getSession(RemoteConnectionPool.java:144)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1709)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Error signing certificate verify
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1886)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(ClientHandshaker.java:987)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:285)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1016)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection$6.run(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1280)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection$6.run(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1273)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.protocolConnect(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1271)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA224withRSA Signature not available
        at java.security.Signature.getInstance(Signature.java:224)
        at sun.security.ssl.JsseJce.getSignature(JsseJce.java:241)
        at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeMessage$CertificateVerify.<init>(HandshakeMessage.java:1552)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(ClientHandshaker.java:982)
        ... 29 more
```

**from AMQERR01.LOG**

```
----- amqrmrsa.c : 930 --------------------------------------------------------
01/31/2017 08:45:00 PM - Process(14444.328) User(mqm) Program(amqrmppa)
                    Host(testvm) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(7.1.0.7) QMgr(TLSTEST.QM)

AMQ9665: SSL connection closed by remote end of channel '????'.

EXPLANATION:
The SSL or TLS connection was closed by the remote host 'localhost (127.0.0.1)'
during the secure socket handshake. The channel is '????'; in some cases its
name cannot be determined and so is shown as '????'. The channel did not start.
ACTION:
Check the remote end of the channel for SSL and TLS errors. Fix them and
restart the channel.
----- amqccisa.c : 6478 -------------------------------------------------------
01/31/2017 08:45:00 PM - Process(14444.328) User(mqm) Program(amqrmppa)
                    Host(testvm) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(7.1.0.7) QMgr(TLSTEST.QM)

AMQ9492: The TCP/IP responder program encountered an error.

EXPLANATION:
The responder program was started but detected an error. 

The host name was 'localhost (127.0.0.1)'; in some cases the host name cannot
be determined and so is shown as '????'.
ACTION:
Look at previous error messages in the error files to determine the error
encountered by the responder program.
----- amqrmrsa.c : 930 --------------------------------------------------------
```

**removed old jars from classpath , but still same exception**

**Console Output have below lines printed for Algorithm**

```
matching alias: ibmwebspheremqtlstest.qm
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA,
```

*In client , passing key.jks file , which is created at MQ level with 'runmqckm'

whether need to specify different Algorithm on creation for TLSv2 ?*

> TLSV2 WORKED WITH JDK8  and  ibm/java-x86_64-71

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
```

**Oracle JDK8**

```
MQEnvironment.sslFipsRequired = false;  
MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256";  
ALTER CHANNEL(TEST.CH) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) SSLCIPH(TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256)
```

**IBM-JDK 7.1**

```
MQEnvironment.sslFipsRequired = false;
MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite = "SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256";
ALTER CHANNEL(TEST.CH) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) SSLCIPH(TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256)
```

**But question on** how to work any TLSv2 cipher with lesser version of Oracle java than 8?

To resolve/work-around the issue:**will try one by one**

1) use the IBM JVM
2) test with Oracle Java v8
3) Try MQ v8
4) other option to set `SSLCAUTH=OPTIONAL` and not require client side certificate.

> Trying with  JDK8  and  MQ8

Now Trying to do the same with JDK8 + MQ8 , MQServer8 and MQSeriesGSKit-8.0.0-4.x86_64 installed , but now issue with creating certificate with runmqckm command

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/mqm/gskit8/lib64  
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/mqm/gskit8/bin  
runmqckm  

bash: runmqckm: command not found
```

partially Worked with runmqakm
But failed to create jks files as below

```
runmqakm  -keydb -create  -db /var/mqm/qmgrs/TLSTEST\!QM/ssl/key.jks  -pw password  -type jks  
CTGSK3017W The database type "jks" is not recognized.
```

**Resolved**

No Need to set below path

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/mqm/gskit8/lib64  
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/mqm/gskit8/bin
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IBM MQ [Fix Pack 7.1.0.7](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27024302#7107) released November 19th 2015 includes the following APAR:

[IV73396: DEPRECATION OF SSLV3 CIPHERSPECS IN WEBSPHERE MQ V7 QUEUE MANAGERS](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV73396)

> PROBLEM DESCRIPTION:
>
> Once this change is applied, any queue managers created will disallow the use of the following CipherSpecs on channel definitions associated with the queue manager:

> `AES_SHA_US`
> **`RC4_SHA_US`**
> `RC4_MD5_US`
> `TRIPLE_DES_SHA_US`
> `DES_SHA_EXPORT1024`
> `RC4_56_SHA_EXPORT1024`
> `RC4_MD5_EXPORT`
> `RC2_MD5_EXPORT`
> `DES_SHA_EXPORT`
> `NULL_SHA`
> `NULL_MD5`
> `FIPS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA`
> `FIPS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA`
>
> Attempting to use or configure one of these CipherSpecs will result in one or more of the following messages in the queue manager error log: AMQ8242, **AMQ9616**, AMQ9635.

---

This was a result of SSLv3 being formally deprecated in June 2015 as a result of the IETF approving and publishing [RFC7568](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7568)

> 1. Introduction
>
> Since it was released in 1996, the SSLv3 protocol [[RFC6101](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6101)] has been subject to a long series of attacks, both on its key exchange mechanism and on the encryption schemes it supports.  Despite being replaced by TLS 1.0 [[RFC2246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2246)] in 1999, and subsequently TLS 1.1 in 2002 [[RFC4346](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4346)] and 1.2 in 2006 [[RFC5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246)], availability of these replacement versions has not been universal.  As a result, many implementations of TLS have permitted the negotiation of SSLv3.
>
> The predecessor of SSLv3, SSL version 2, is no longer considered sufficiently secure [[RFC6176](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6176)].  SSLv3 now follows.

---

There is a very good IBM developerWorks blog post "[SSL and TLS Cipher Specification Deprecations for the MQ Product](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/aimsupport/entry/ssl_and_tls_cipher_specification_deprecations_for_the_mq_product?lang=en)" posted May 19 2016 by Miguel A. Rodriguez that goes into detail about which ciphers are deprecated in various Fix Packs.

---

I would recommend that you find a supported TLSv1.2 cipher to use that is compatible with both the Java client and the IBM MQ SVRCONN channel.  There were many updates as a result of SSLv3 being deprecated which opened up more TLS ciphers to Java clients using either IBM or Non-IBM JREs.

A good write up about the changes IBM made to the Java client cipher support is IBM developerWorks blog post "[MQ Java, TLS Ciphers, Non-IBM JREs & APARs IT06775, IV66840, IT09423, IT10837 -- HELP ME PLEASE!](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/MQ_Java_TLS_Ciphers_Non_IBM_JREs_APARs_IT06775_IV66840_IT09423_IT10837_HELP_ME_PLEASE?lang=en)" posted on June 9th 2016 by Tom Leend.

---

The reason you do not have a problem with IBM MQ v6.0.2.12 is because that version has been out of support for over four years (since September 30th 2012) and IBM would not release any security updates for a End of Service version like it does for supported versions.

---

I would recommend that you move to a supported version of IBM MQ.  When considering which version to upgrade to, note that two of the ***currently*** supported versions will be going out of support over the next 16 months:

- MQ v7.1 goes out of support in less than four months on **April 30th 2017**.
- MQ v7.5 goes out of support on **April 30th 2018**.
- MQ v8.0 and v9.0 do not have currently announced end of support dates.

---

IBM developerWorks blog post "[MQ Java, TLS Ciphers, Non-IBM JREs & APARs IT06775, IV66840, IT09423, IT10837 -- HELP ME PLEASE!](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/MQ_Java_TLS_Ciphers_Non_IBM_JREs_APARs_IT06775_IV66840_IT09423_IT10837_HELP_ME_PLEASE?lang=en)" states that APAR [IV66840](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV66840) which added the `useIBMCipherMappings` setting is included in 7.1.0.7 and this should allow the use of TLSv1.2 Cipherspecs with a Oracle JRE.

The table in the APAR [IV66840](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV66840) has this information:

> The following WebSphere MQ CipherSuite to CipherSpec mappings have
> been enabled by this APAR for WebSphere MQ v7.1 and v7.5 where the
> classes for Java and classes for JMS support SHA-2:￴
>
> ```
> Oracle CipherSuite              IBM MQ CipherSpec
> TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256        TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256
> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
> TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
> ```

If you compare that to the v7.1 Knowledge center page [Specifying CipherSpecs](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.doc/sy12870_.htm), you find that all three of those are TLSv1.2 Cipherspecs.

For comparison with the IBM JRE Ciphersuite name, the v7.1 Knowledge center page [SSL CipherSpecs and CipherSuites in WebSphere MQ classes for Java](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.doc/ja34740_.htm) lists a similar mapping:

```
IBM CipherSuite                 IBM MQ CipherSpec
SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256        TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256
SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA    TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
```

---

> ***UPDATE (2017/01/27) to address further questions***

The MQ CipherSpec TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA256 is not one of those listed in APAR [IV66840](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV66840) has having been enabled for non-IBM JREs under MQ v7.1, it is only listed under v8.0.  Above I listed the three TLSv1.2 CipherSpecs that were added to MQ v7.1.

I would suggest you try TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 as the CipherSpec on the MQ channel and TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 as the Java CipherSuite.

The settings below should work with the my suggested CipherSpec/CipherSuite, please note that I changed it from `TLSv1` to `TLSv1.2`

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.preferTLS=true
-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false
```

---

> ***UPDATE (2017/01/30) to try and address further questions***

In your question you mention these jar files in your classpath: `/tmp/mqssl/com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar:/tmp/mqssl/com.ibm.mq.jar`

Will you please confirm which version of the IBM MQ product each of these are from, you can do this on linux with the unzip utility:

`unzip -p com.ibm.mq.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF|grep Implementation-Version`

Output will be:

`Implementation-Version: x.x.x.x - pxxx-xxx-YYMMDD`

---

> ***UPDATE (2017/01/31) to address further questions***

APAR [IV66840](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV66840) which includes the `-Dcom.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false` setting is not included in MQ until v7.1.0.7, this is the version you stated is being used.

Based on the output you provided the jar files you are referencing are from a v7.1.0.1 install which does **not** include support for TLS on non-IBM JREs such as Oracle JRE.

---

You also note that the jar files are in `/tmp/mqssl`, please note that prior to v8 of MQ IBM does not support copying the jar files outside of the default location where they are installed.

IBM Technote "[Supported way to install WebSphere MQ Java jar files, JMS jar files, or C/C++ libraries](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21376217)" states:

> +++ Section 1: MQ 7.x
>
> The only supported way to get the MQ jar files or the MQ C/C++ library files onto a system is to install either:
>
> - the WebSphere MQ product or
> - the WebSphere MQ Client SupportPacs.
>
> To legally download and use a client you must first accept the terms and conditions specified in the License Agreement.
>
> Do not copy the WebSphere MQ jar files to application EAR or WAR files.
>
> Do not copy the WebSphere MQ jar or MQ C/C++ library files from other machines:
>
> - Fix Packs cannot be applied to an "installation" where jar or C/C++ library files have been copied from another machine, and this makes it much more difficult to ensure that all of these jar/library files are kept in step with each other, and are at compatible levels.
> - Copying jar/library files between machines can also result in multiple copies of the files residing on the same machine, which can cause problems servicing the code and debugging problems.

---

If your application is on the same server as the MQ v7.1.0.7 Queue Manager then you can just reference the jar file that are in the directory `/opt/mqm/java/lib`.

If your application is not on the same server and you plan to stay with v7.1 or go with v7.5 I would recommend installing the latest full client install, see my note above on suggestions for versions based on when they are End of Service.

---

If you decide to go with v8 or v9, IBM Technote "[Supported way to install WebSphere MQ Java jar files, JMS jar files, or C/C++ libraries](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21376217)" also states:

> b) Starting with MQ 8.0.0.4, you can use Redistributable files:
>
> - [Installation scenarios for MQ 8.0 and 9.0 in Linux and Windows](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27048266) - Chapter 8: You need to redistribute MQ runtime libraries with your application.
> - [How to download the MQ 8.0.0.4+ and MQ 9.0.0.x redistributable client images for Linux x86-64 and Windows 64-bit](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/238072/how-to-download-the-mq-8004-redistributable-client.html)
> - [Bitesize Blogging: MQ 8.0.0.4 Redistributable Clients](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/Bitesize_Blogging_MQ_8_0_0_4_Redistributable_Clients?lang=en)

What this means is that with v8.0.0.4 and higher you can download a MQ JMS and Java only redistributable client.

The MQ JMS and Java only redistributable client client packages are available from FixCentral [here](https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?product=ibm/WebSphere/WebSphere+MQ&release=All&platform=All&function=textSearch&text=MQ+Java+Redistributable&source=fc).

---

> ***UPDATE (2017/01/31 A) to address further questions***

After searching on the error you are receiving I found this dW Answers post "[Why do I get AMQ9771, 2393 SSL Initialization error from a MQ Java/JMS application when trying to use an TLS AES 256 cipher?](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/189995/why-do-i-get-amq9771-2393-ssl-initialization-error/)".  It states that the following:

> In this case, the issue is caused by attempting to use AES 256 strong
> cipher algorithms.
>
> Most Java JREs, including Oracle/Sun and IBM's have Import Limits on
> Cryptographic Algorithms enabled. This limits the maximum key sizes
> and also some algorithms.
>
> When trying to use a AES 256 cipher, such as
> ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 or **TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256** with a
> MQ Java/JMS application, you need to ensure your JRE supports this
> cipher. In most cases, when the stronger cipher algorithms are needed,
> such as AES 256 ciphers, the JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction
> Policy Files must be obtained and installed in the JDK/JRE.
>
> This is noted in the JDK/JRE documentation: For Oracle 1.7:
>
> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html

The link above to the oracle site states:

> If stronger algorithms are needed (for example, AES with 256-bit
> keys), the [JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) must be
> obtained and installed in the JDK/JRE.
>
> It is the user's responsibility to verify that this action is
> permissible under local regulations.

I would suggest that you either use the lower CipherSuite `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256`, or follow the advise above to obtain and install the ***JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files***.

---

> ***UPDATE (2017/02/01) to address further questions***

The error that caught my eye was `Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA224withRSA Signature not available`.

I searched on google for this and found the following dW Answers post "[How to resolve issue with MQ v7.x Java client getting SSL error NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA224withRSA Signature not available?](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/251057/how-to-resolve-issue-with-mq-v7x-java-client-getti.html)" which states the following:

> Assuming using Oracle JVM:
>
> We have found that the root cause of the issue is the signature
> algorithm SHA224withRSA is   not supported by Oracle JRE 1.7, see
> signature algorithms available:
>
> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html

In the above link the table of interest is under "[The SunRsaSign Provider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunRsaSignProvider)" which lists the following supported signature algorithms:

> `MD2withRSA`
> `MD5withRSA`
> `SHA1withRSA`
> `SHA256withRSA`
> `SHA384withRSA`
> `SHA512withRSA`

Note that `SHA224withRSA` is **not** on the list.

---

The same dW Answers post goes on to state:

> This signature algorithm is available in the IBM JVM and also in
> Oracle JVM 1.8.
>
> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html

In the above link the table of interest is under "[The SunRsaSign Provider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html?cm_mc_uid=52990415819214807498475&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1485919991#SunRsaSignProvider)" which lists the following supported signature algorithms:

> `MD2withRSA`
> `MD5withRSA`
> `SHA1withRSA`
> ***`SHA224withRSA`***
> `SHA256withRSA`
> `SHA384withRSA`
> `SHA512withRSA`

Note that `SHA224withRSA` **is** on the list.

---

Recommendations from the dW post:

1. Try with Oracle Java 8 (1.8)
2. Try with IBM Java

---

> ***UPDATE (2017/02/01 B) to address further questions***

Taking into account all of the information gathered through the troubleshooting above the answer is that it is not possible to use a TLSv1.2 cipher with a Oracle Java less than 8 using MQ v7.1.0.7 MQ Java client.

Based on the last dW Answers post I provided, IBM suggested trying with MQ v8, but I do not think they tested this configuration so it may also not work.

If you do want to try with MQ v8 I would suggest you go with the latest v8.0.0.5 Java only redistributable client client packages which I provided links already.