# AMQ9776: Channel was blocked

Tags: ibm-mq

I need help, I have the following issue:

```
AMQ9776: Channel was blocked by userid 

EXPLANATION: 
The inbound channel 'TEST1.SRVCONN' was blocked from address '10.0.2.4' 
because the active values of the channel were mapped to a userid which should 
be blocked. The active values of the channel were 'MCAUSER(mqm) CLNTUSER(mqm)'.
```

And I have the following authorities records:

```
DISPLAY CHLAUTH(*)
    37 : DISPLAY CHLAUTH(*)
AMQ8878: Ver detalles de registro de autenticación de canal.
   CHLAUTH(SYSTEM.ADMIN.SVRCONN)           TYPE(ADDRESSMAP)
   ADDRESS(*)                              USERSRC(CHANNEL)

AMQ8878: Ver detalles de registro de autenticación de canal.
   CHLAUTH(TEST1.SRVCNN)                   TYPE(ADDRESSMAP)
   ADDRESS(10.0.2.4)                       USERSRC(CHANNEL)

AMQ8878: Ver detalles de registro de autenticación de canal.
   CHLAUTH(TEST1.SRVCNN)                   TYPE(BLOCKUSER)
   USERLIST(mqm)                        

AMQ8878: Ver detalles de registro de autenticación de canal.
   CHLAUTH(SYSTEM.*)                       TYPE(ADDRESSMAP)
   ADDRESS(*)                              USERSRC(NOACCESS)

AMQ8878: Ver detalles de registro de autenticación de canal.
   CHLAUTH(*)                              TYPE(BLOCKUSER)
   USERLIST(*MQADMIN)
```

So I don't know what else I can do, I had been reading about this problem and I created the rule to connect to the channel and I granted privilege to the user. ¿What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that for MQ v8 and later when MQ compares the MQ client user to the `USERLIST` of a `TYPE(BLOCKUSER)` rule or to the `CLNTUSER` on a `TYPE(USERMAP)` rule, it can be set to look at either the user the client process is running under or at the user that is presented in the MQCSP and successfully authenticated by CONNAUTH.  To get the later behavior you must have `ChlauthEarlyAdopt=y` set in the `Channels:` stanza of the `qm.ini`.  For new queue managers created under MQ v8.0 LTS and MQ v9.0 LTS the default would NOT be to set this and MQ will look at the user the client process is running under.  For MQ v9.0.5 CD, MQ v9.1 LTS, and MQ v9.1 CD the default is to have it set and MQ will look at the user sent in the MQCSP and successfully authenticated by CONNAUTH.

Note the `ChlauthEarlyAdopt` setting was added at 8.0.0.5, prior to this it would always look at the user the client process is running under.

---

By default MQ comes with the following rule:

```
CHLAUTH(*)                              TYPE(BLOCKUSER)
USERLIST(*MQADMIN)
```

That rule blocks all users which MQ deems to have MQ Administrative authority from connecting to ANY `SVRCONN` channel on the queue manager.

---

You added the following two rules (note unless you add ALL to your DISPLAY command it will not show all attributes, so I can only discuss what you show):

```
AMQ8878: Ver detalles de registro de autenticación de canal.
   CHLAUTH(TEST1.SRVCNN)                   TYPE(ADDRESSMAP)
   ADDRESS(10.0.2.4)                       USERSRC(CHANNEL)

AMQ8878: Ver detalles de registro de autenticación de canal.
   CHLAUTH(TEST1.SRVCNN)                   TYPE(BLOCKUSER)
   USERLIST(mqm)
```

---

The first (`TYPE(ADDRESSMAP)`) will allow a connection from `ADDRESS(10.0.2.4)` to this channel and leave the user set to what is negotiated on the channel.  But absent any other MAP rule that blocks connections by setting `USERSRC(NOACCESS)`, this rule really does not do anything.

If you have a `SVRCONN` channel that has a blank `MCAUSER` then MQ will accept the username that is sent from the client.  For most clients this is the user the process is running under, for Java and JMS it is very easy to send any user including a blank value.  If both user sent by the client and `MCAUSER` on the channel are blank then the negotiated `MCAUSER` will be the user the message channel agent process is running under, on unix this would normally be `mqm`.

---

The second rule (`TYPE(BLOCKUSER)`) is actually telling MQ specifically to block any channel where the user is `mqm` is sent from the client, this is likely the opposite of what you were trying to accomplish.

---

If the client connecting is not an administrative application, then the best way to fix this would be to define another user and give that user permission to what it needs.

See my answer to the following question for more details on how to provide MQ permissions to a low privledge user: [Authorization errors with MQ8 + JDk8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42347461/authorization-errors-with-mq8-jdk8/42351613#42351613)

It would not be a good practice to allow applications to connect to a SVRCONN channel that has no security, you do not mention if you are using `CONNAUTH` or `TLS` certs to provide security on the channel, but if you are not you should use one or the other to lock down who can connect to the channel.

Comment: Hi, yes I'm using CONNAUTH:

    1 : DISPLAY QMGR CONNAUTH
AMQ8408: Display Queue Manager details.
   QMNAME(QM_TEST1)                     
   CONNAUTH(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS)

Or is anothe way to verify who can connect to the channel?

Comment: Any ID that is administrative will fail to connect less you specifically disable the check for that channel.  If you are going to use `CONNAUTH` you should set `ChlauthEarlyAdopt=y` and on the `AUTHINFO` object set `ADOPTCTX(YES)`.  If all client connections will require CONNAUTH then set `CHCKCLNT(REQUIRED)`  at the `AUTHINFO` object level.  If only some channels require CONNAUTH then set `CHCKCLNT(OPTIONAL)` at the `AUTHINFO` level and then use a `CHLAUTH` rule that matches the channel to uplift it to `CHCKCLNT(REQUIRED)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. :) I get it