# MQ9 + oracle-JDK8 Cipersuites and Cipher Specs

Tags: ibm-mq, java-8

What Cipersuites and Cipher Specs, can I use for IBM MQ v9 + Oracle-JDK v8?

I need more information on the FIPS parameter. When I tried with FIPS parameter, I didn't change anything in MQ level, but changed it to true in JMS client. What is use of this? How is it related to cipher-spec or cipher-suite?

> Getting Authorization exception in MQ9 and resolved

just want to review below process are correct way to avoid Authorization exception

- setmqaut -m TLSTEST.QM -t qmgr -p clientadmin +connect +dsp +inq
- setmqaut -m TLSTEST.QM -t queue -p clientadmin -n '**' +put +get
  +browse +dsp +inq
- runmqsc TLSTEST.QM ALTER AUTHINFO(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS)
  AUTHTYPE(IDPWOS) CHCKCLNT(OPTIONAL)
- ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH(DISABLED)
- REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(CONNAUTH)

Comment: Have I answered your question?

Comment: I would recommend that you edit and remove the text from your question about Authorization exception since this is unrelated to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information already provided in my answer to your question "[TLSv2 with JDk8 Ciphersuites with MQ8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42191793/tlsv2-with-jdk8-ciphersuites-with-mq8/42200231#42200231) regarding MQ8 + Oracle-JDK8 will apply to this question.

Per a presentation given by Mark Taylor "[What’s new in IBM MQ?](http://www.mqtechconference.com/sessions_v2016/MQTC_2016_Whats_new_in_MQ.pdf)", the GA release of MQ v9.0.0.0 was based on MQ v8.0.0.4 plus functional changes.

> – Plus functional changes on top of MQ 8.0.0.4…

APAR [IV66840](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IV66840) shows the fix is targeted for delivery in 8.0.0.2.

Based on this v9.0.0.0 would have this APAR included with the same Oracle mapping available in v8.0.0.2 and higher.

---

For information on FIPS please refer to the IBM MQ v9.0 Knowledge Center page "[Federal Information Processing Standards (FIPS)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q010140_.htm).

In general this caused MQ to disable weak cipherspecs.

In relation to Java, the settings like sslFipsRequired would cause MQ to use TLS in preference to SSL for Cipersuites that had a dual mapping, but as of any recent version of MQ any of those Ciphersuites that had dual mapping have been disabled by default as weak Ciphersuits.

IBM developerWorks blog post "[MQ Java, TLS Ciphers, Non-IBM JREs & APARs IT06775, IV66840, IT09423, IT10837 -- HELP ME PLEASE!](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/messaging/entry/MQ_Java_TLS_Ciphers_Non_IBM_JREs_APARs_IT06775_IV66840_IT09423_IT10837_HELP_ME_PLEASE?lang=en)" has details on how the sslFipsRequired and preferTLS behavior has changed over recent APARs.

Comment: Referring to FIPS , what is use of this? how it related to cipher-spec or cipher-suite? even though in MQ Level , NOT enabled this parameter , JMS client getting connected.In Some Docs mentioned on cipher-spec<>ciper-suite-FIPS value

Comment: New question added for easy migration process in windows MQ8/9 server installtion  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43030276/migration-process-from-mq7-to-mq8-mq9]

Comment: Please do not use comments to old questions to reference new questions.  All you need to do is tag the new question with the tag [[tag:ibm-mq]] and people with knowledge of the IBM MQ product will see it.  I would recommend going back and deleting the comments to your past questions where you reference new questions as well as editing past questions to remove links to new questions.