# MQ Migration Process steps from lower version to Higher version[ MQ7 to MQ9]

Tags: ibm-mq

Current version running is MQ7 in windows 2008 server. What to know about migration process steps from MQ7 to MQ8/MQ9?.New Version of MQ8/MQ9 Server to be installed and how existing Queue definition can be migrated?

1. Will Server Installation take care of QM definition also?
2. windows 2008 server will be good for mq9?
3. There is a MQ-Client7 contacting MQ-Server7, so if we upgrade MQ7 to MQ9 then MQ-Client also will be upgraded to MQ9?
4. There will be any issue in contacting MQ9-Client to MQ7 Server?
5. dspmqver will give MQ server details , how to verify MQ-Client version?

Answer (score 1):

If you install the new version (V8 or V9) as an upgrade to the V7 installation on the same machine then then next time you start the queue manager it will be migrated to the new version.

If you install the new version alongside the V7 installation on the same machine, then you have to use the `setmqm` command to force the queue manager to move from V7 to the new version.

If you install the new version on a completely different machine, the no automatic migration can take place. You will have to create a brand new queue manager and then copy across the definitions from the old one.

The command to export all the object definitions is:

```
dmpmqcfg -m QM1 -x all > DEFS.mqs
```

The command to import all the object definitions is:

```
runmqsc QM1 < DEFS.mqs
```

The system requirements (e.g. minimum O/S levels) are documented by IBM [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27006467).

There is no requirement for the MQ Client to be the same version as the MQ Queue Manager. The MQ Client can be a higher version or a lower version than the MQ Queue Manager and still operate perfectly. The only thing to remember if the MQ Client is a higher version than the MQ Queue Manager is that new features cannot yet be used.

You can see the version of the MQ Client being used when it connects to the queue manager by looking in `DISPLAY CHSTATUS` for the field called `RVERSION`.

Comment: is **'setmqm'** command used in command prompt of windows on while install of new version? Normally there will be a Setup.exe file for installation right?could you elaborate on installation steps or site which i can refer for install and smooth migration.

Comment: The setmqm command is used AFTER you have done the installation. It has nothing to do with the INSTALLATION, it only has to do with assigning the queue manager to the new level of code once that installation has been completed.

Comment: If you don't want to have two different versions of MQ side by side, you can simply do the installation in place over the top of the old one as you would have done in a previous release and then you don't need to worry about setmqm. There are very detailed steps in the IBM Knowledge Center.

Comment: There is plan for new Server for MQ9 and certain QM's signatures and Settings should perform export and import(migration).How i can export and import few QM's on new MQ9 server after install.

Comment: That information seems pertinent to your original question. Perhaps you should update to the question to say that the new version is on a different machine. My answer is only for when the new version is on the same machine. Do you only need to export the definitions from the QMgrs or do you also need to export messages from queues on the QMgrs?

Comment: i am in process of migration from MQ7.0 to MQ9 on windows. Problem is i could not able to find 64 bit MQ7.0 Server. IBM site have MQ7.0 32 bit only. When installed MQ7.0 32bit on 64 bit windows, Throwing error as unsupported version. i Can do the same exercise as you mentioned with MQ7.1 to MQ9,0 right?

Comment: export the definitions from the QMgrs only required, Question is simple , we are trying to Install MQ9 in new windows server. All QMgrs definitions should move from MQ7 to MQ9(using some export + import )

Comment: This is really valuable help..we will try to export and import, from one server to new server..will validate on all definitions has been moved or not.

Comment: What changes in [ dmpmqcfg -m TLSTEST -x all > QMDEFS.mqs ][ runmqsc TLSTEST < QMDEFS.mqs ] to import all QM's with one shot?

Comment: Nothing. You have to do each queue manager one at a time. You could put the commands into a script if you want to run one job, but since this is a one-off task writing the script won't save you anything over just running the commands. Your choice. How many queue managers do you have?