# Exception in connectioncom.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2400'

Tags: java, jmeter, ssl-certificate, ibm-mq, loadrunner

I'm trying to connect to MQ queue manager which uses 1 way SSL using Java client. Even after following all the steps mentioned in various blogs, I am still getting MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2400' error.

Please find the java code we are using:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Copying and pasting steps without understanding what they're doing isn't the best way to proceed. The same applies to pasting code as image here.

As per [2400 (0960) (RC2400)](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/8.0?topic=codes-2400-0960-rc2400-mqrc-unsupported-cipher-suite) error description:

> A connection to a queue manager was requested, specifying SSL encryption. However, JSSE reported that it does not support the CipherSuite specified by the application.
>
> Check the CipherSuite specified by the application. Note that the names of JSSE CipherSuites differ from their equivalent CipherSpecs used by the queue manager.
>
> Also, check that JSSE is correctly installed.

So you're trying to use cipher suite which might be supported by MQ but it's not supported by your local Java installation. You could try using [Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files](https://www.oracle.com/pl/java/technologies/javase-jce8-downloads.html) or obtaining the JDK from your MQ machine which should have the this `ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA384` cipher suite installed.

More information:

- [TLSv2 with JDk8 Ciphersuites with MQ8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42191793/tlsv2-with-jdk8-ciphersuites-with-mq8)
- [IBM MQ testing with JMeter - Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/ibm-mq-testing-with-jmeter-learn-how)

Answer (score 0):

IBM MQ error 2400 means [UNSUPPORTED_CIPHER_SUITE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=codes-2400-0960-rc2400-mqrc-unsupported-cipher-suite).

Depending on the JDK vendor (IBM/Oracle), you can enable [CipherSuite mapping](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=jms-tls-cipherspecs-ciphersuites-in-mq-classes#q113220___mappings1) with Java system property `com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings`. Based on your screenshot you want to use `ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA384`. If you use the Oracle JDK, you have to do this in Java:

```
System.setProperty("com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings", "false");
...
MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite = "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384";
```

If you are using MQ 9.2, you can also simply configure cipher suite `*TLS12ORHIGHER`.

Comment: Note that to use `*TLS12ORHIGHER` on the Java client side the queue manager SVRCONN channel must be set to `ANY_TLS12_OR_HIGHER`.

Comment: @JoshMc You are right. Just had a debugging session today with an MQ server on zOS, and there the cipher alias for the SDR channel did not work and we had to use a fixed cipher; but for the RCVR channel the cipher alias was fine.

Comment: It applies to any channel that is being connected to,  you can always set them to one of the ANY values (SVRCONN, RCVR, SVR or RQSTR that are receiving the connection) the exception is a CLUSRCVR, it shouldn't be updated until all queue managers in the cluster are at 9.2.

Answer (score 0):

What you are specifying is the queue manager CipherSpec, below is the table from [CipherSuite mapping](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=jms-tls-cipherspecs-ciphersuites-in-mq-classes) IBM Docs page showing which CipherSuite to use depending on the Java provider.

| CipherSpec Equivalent | CipherSuite (IBM JRE) Equivalent | CipherSuite (Oracle JRE) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 | SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 | TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 |

If you are not using IBM JRE then you must specify the java system property:

```
com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings=false
```